# Populate Spinner using SQLite3 row entries (Cursor) AND a String

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, android-spinner

So I want to populate a Spinner with a String like "All", followed by all entries of a SQLite db. I've searched on how to do so without any luck. I have everything setup to handle entries for the selection of "All" or the actual entries, but I don't know how to add the entry "All" to the spinner or the adapter.

I'm currently using a SimpleCursorAdapter(which I know is deprecated). Should I use some other type of Adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should create dynamic array for spinner And add data in array

```
List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
arrayList.add("All");
```

Now get Data using cursor and add in arrayList(using for loop or while loop add one bye one) And setAdapter with arrayList.

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(YOURCLASSNAME.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,arrayList);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I never used ArrayAdapters before so I wasn't really sure if this was where to use em.